# Presheaf problem

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, sheaf-theory, fiber-bundles, topos-theory

I need to show that the global element of a presheaf $P\in \widehat{\mathcal{O}(X)}$ is equivalent to global section of bundle of germs $\Lambda_P\xrightarrow{p}X$. In particular, I need help to show that if we suppose the existence of a global section of $\Lambda_P\xrightarrow{p}X$ then we can define a global element of presheaf. I was thinking that if $P(X)\ne \emptyset$ is easy then to show that exist a global element but i still don't prove that.

Comment: You haven't defined your symbols...

Comment: $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{O}(X)$ Is the topology ordered by inclusion regarded as category. $\Lambda_P$ represents the set of all germs: two elements $s\in P(U)$ and $t \in P(V)$, where $U$ e $V$ are two open neighborhoods of a point $x$ of $X$, are said to have "the same germ in $x$" if there exists and open neighborhoods $W$ of $x$ contained in $U\cap V$ such that $s|W = t|W$. By $s|W$ i mean clearly $P(W\subset U) (s)$. Is this enough?

Comment: OK. So the problem is that the claim is false. There is a bijection between global elements of $P$ and global sections of $\Lambda_P \to X$ if $P$ is a _sheaf_. You can find a counterexample if $P$ is just a presheaf. (For example, just take any presheaf you like and replace $P (X)$ with $\emptyset$.)

Comment: And the same holds for partial elements and partial sections? With "partial elements of P" I mean a Natural map U->P where U is a subfunctor of P.

Comment: Yes. The restriction of a sheaf is a sheaf.

Comment: I've meant: consider a small category $\mathbf{C}$ and define a "local element" of $P\in\hat{\mathbf{C}}$ a natural map between $H$, subfunctor of $1$ (terminal object of $\hat{\mathbf{C}}$), and $P$. This is then a more general definition of global elements. If $\mathbf{C}$ is the topology of topological space $X$ ordered by inclusion and $P$ is a sheaf on $X$ are the concepts of local section of bundle of germs on $P$ and local element of $P$ the same?